# chrome.fileSystem - retain/restore multiple file entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I have two functions: `saveData()` and `loadData()`. `saveData()` runs through all of the objects and (supposedly) sets a string ID and value with `chrome.storage.local.set` to be returned later with `loadData()`. Now, I say supposedly because it doesn't work. The result when restarting the app is *only* the last entry saved.

```
//I have an array 
//called 'fileEntries'
//which the user adds fileEntry objects to
//when they add a tab or open a file
var fileEntries = [];
function saveData(){ 
  fileEntries.forEach(function(entry){
    //the string id should just be the
    //index of the entry object within the array
    //so something like '1' or '2'
    var stringID = fileEntries.indexOf(entry),
        value = chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(entry);
    chrome.storage.local.set({ stringID : value });
  });
}
function loadData(){
  chrome.storage.local.get({stringID : null}, function(result){
    chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(result.stringID, function(entry){
      //adds the resulting entry into the array
      fileEntries.push(entry);
    })
  })
}
```

Does anyone know how to help? It's really been bothering me, I've tried a bunch of other methods to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**If the question isn't clear**: how can i save multiple file entries and then restore them individually using the chrome fileSystem API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter of [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ; e.g.; `.forEach(function(_, enttry){})`, where `entry` is the `index` of the iterated element within the array. The first parameter to `.forEach()` callback being the `value`. If the `value` will not be used you can use an underscore to indicate omission of its usage. Then you can still use the existing `entry` variable names within the remainder of `js` at `.forEach()` callback.

Comment: Okay I edited it and the result stays the same. The problem wasn't that part of the code. It has to do with that the `index` value ('1', or '2' or whatever number) is being read as 'index' rather than a number itself. I need it to set a number value with the entry object for each object in the array _individually_ and then get the entries individually aswell and add it to the `fileEntries` array that I have. Thanks for the answer though, cleaned up my code a little!

Comment: @Devplex Are you trying to retrieve the index of the `entry` object within `fileEntries`, or a property of the `entry` object itself ?

Comment: None of those XD sorry if i'm not being very clear. I want to set the fileEntries individually and retrieve them individually. once thats done add it to the `fileEntries` array. The `stringID` is just what I want each object to be stored as and the `value` is the resulting ID when the `entry` object is passed on to the `chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry()` function.

Comment: Not following . Are you trying to add items to `fileEntries` at `saveData` function ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a key with the `entry` as a value for each object in the `fileEntries` array. Then I'm trying to retrieve all of those values when the user restarts the app.

Comment: What do you mean by "make a key" ? Can you include an example of `fileEntries` at Question, and what expected result is ?

Comment: This : `chrome.storage.local.set({ stringID : value });` is composed of a key and a value. The key should be the index of the object and the value is the string id returned by the retainEntry function.

Comment: You can use the `index` at `.forEach(function(entry, index){})` where `index` is the index of `entry` within `fileEntries` . `.indexOf()` is not necessary if you are trying to find the index of `entry` within `fileEntries`

Comment: I know. I did that, like you said. But it didnt change the result. the `stringID` is treated like an actual string rather than the variable it stands for.

Comment: Is `stringID` expected to be a number ?

Comment: Yes, it should be a number that represents the index of the entry,

Comment: Try `Number(stringID)`